# Laravel: Grab data from the Controller from inside a view composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Atm I'm creating this view composer for fun. It is collecting .js filenames and then passing it to the layout to be linked. The filenames used depend on the current page. For example a lower ranked page like Slides, doesn't include  ajax requests used in UserManagement. Please don't ask me why I would do this xD. Im planning to validate requests anyway. Just being bored.

Anyways, as I'm quite new to laravel I'm still looking for more efficient ways to do things. 
Atm Im accessing the file names staticly. The Controller now looks like this

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public static $js_file_names = [];
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

In the pagecontroller I construct the filenames:

```
class SlidesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::$js_file_names = ['ccs', 'ajax-updates'];
    }
```

And finaly I retreive them inside the registered Viewcomposer like this:
(during development $use_filenames has all files as default)

```
public function __construct()
{
    $filenames = Controller::$js_file_names;
    if( !empty($filenames) )
        $this->use_filenames = $filenames;

    var_dump($this->use_filenames);die;
}
```

It all seems to be working fine, but the big question is, is there a better way to access controller data from inside a viewcomposer? Every time I try to google this, I get results like 'passing data to views' etc, which is not rly the problem.

Update:
Another idea I had is to store all the filenames to be used in an array inside the viewcomposer itself, and check if the current page exists in that array. This would keep the controllers cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a view composer doesn't really make sense in this situation. Since your controllers already 'know' which files they intent to share, you may as well just pass them to the view like so:

```
class SlidesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        View::share('user_filenames', ['ccs', 'ajax-updates']);
    }
}
```

A composer is more for sharing concrete elements such as collections of users, a service provider or some other class instance, for example.

Comment: ic, so an array of js files that differs every time, it is not rly concrete? I like the idea of View::share(), I just need to think of a way to default it. Maybe I can instance a class  that takes care of View::share inside the Controller, since its extended by the page controllers

Comment: meh the links are not even a view themself, but just part of it -.O why didn't I think of this, 'view'-composer